# How to override or change the action call in websphere portal 8.0 application

Tags: websphere-portal

What I did.

Step 1: I have made a web page and added Search widget as web content.

when I have seen the view-source code the I have got action call on submit of search button is : action='/wps/myportal/Search/Search%20Center/!ut/p/b1/jZBBDoIwEEXPwgFMP4QWWNbW0EbAaEShG8PCmCYCLozn1xLiwig4u0nemz_5xJCKmK552Etzt33XXN1u2AkQQukY6_SwpeBhTn2q9gHAXkA9AN-HY_BFylUYZUAspYCWy4QVjAIrjP4bQBgHDlAySnJAs__yJwJm_CMxH0iS-Q7ZiB2PgNQfgakXxwu_O5hroVB9eya3tiwrWL3gnvcEg0x68A!!/dl4/d5/L0lJSklKSmchL0lCakFBQXlBQkVRaVFBISEvNEprRnQyUWp2eWpDL1o2X0NHQUg0N0wwMEdQNzkwSURCOTBNTkkwT0kzL1o3X0NHQUg0N0wwMEdQNzkwSURCOTBNTkkwT0E2LzFicVBOWkpqZWRB/'.

Now I want change this action functionality either can I write my own action and How do I do my development so the action developed by me is invoked?.

Answer (score 0):

If you want custom action processing then you should create your own search portlet and use that instead. You can then use the Search and Index API to create your results page.

Comment: Thanks alot chrisr.  Can you please provide me reference to develop my own search portlet.